# Using SearchUPC API and convert string result to JSON

Tags: c#, json, api, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use an online API to retrieve data based on a UPC code and then convert it into an object. One of their methods is to get the data in JSON format.

The result you get looks like this:

```
  {
  "0": {
    "productname": "Play-doh Single Can by Hasbro",
    "imageurl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31ZzLhzYDEL._SL160_.jpg",
    "producturl": "",
    "price": "10.01",
    "currency": "GBP",
    "saleprice": "",
    "storename": "N/A"
  },
  "1": {
    "productname": "PLAY-DOH Compound Tropical Pink - Two, 5 oz Cans (10 oz)",
    "imageurl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51LbjiXtEjL._SL160_.jpg",
    "producturl": "",
    "price": "37.07",
    "currency": "GBP",
    "saleprice": "",
    "storename": "N/A"
  }
}
```

I am using .NET C# 4.5.2 in an 8.1 application. I am trying to use the HttpClient, but I keep getting weird results as if the JSON is not formatted correctly. I plopped it into an online Json editor and it looks fine, so I'm not sure what the issue is. The code I am running is pretty simple. It looks like this.

```
public async Task<string> GetUpc(string upcCode)
{
    var url = "http://www.searchupc.com/handlers/";
    var result = string.Empty;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.searchupc.com/handlers/upcsearch.ashx?request_type=3&access_token=MY_TOKEN&upc=0653569289791");

        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //JToken token = await Task.Run(() => JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine()));

        //string name = (string)token.SelectToken("productname");

        JsonSerializer s = new JsonSerializer();
        var i = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

    }
    return result;
}
```

When I inspect 'i', it is just a string representation of the result from the API. I also tried using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and passed it the string, but it still just returns a an object that has the string representation over and over again. It's like it knows it's a json object but the format is wrong.

The only solution I figured out so far is to use JObject.Parse as a token and then using SelectToken to traverse the tree.

Any ideas what to do? The solution doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the key name is invalid in C# and seeing as the keys are unique, I think the easiest way would be to parse this into a `Dictionary<string, Foo>`, where `Foo` is declared like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ProductUrl { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string SalePrice { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Foo>>(json);
```

Given your sample JSON, this is the result I get:

[image: Parse Result]

**Side note:**

If you can modify the JSON, it seems like you don't actually have a use for these keys, they're just sequentially incremented, use a list with the `[ ]` notation instead.

Comment: Perfect Thank you. Makes perfect sense now that you say it! I just took that dictionary after that and did a loop to make it a regular list and everything is all set. Thanks again!